# Question about evaluating gem5's HPI core model

Tags: performance, processor, arm64, gem5

gem5 simulator introduced HPI (High-Performance In-order) processor model which is used in ARM system research kit. Although I know that the core model is based on the existing MinorCPU core model, I am curious of how accurately the HPI core model is correlated to other simulator or even real silicon. However, unfortunately, I cannot find research publications relevant to HPI accuracy from academic literature. I believe there is a good reason that HPI uses specific processor configuration values different from base MinorCPU. Can you help me with understanding the accuracy of HPI core model when it is compared to a real ARM CPU?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such public correlation. It is likely very hard to do just by benchmarking / reverse engineering real silicon, and the proprietary details that would be revealed prevent ARM from doing so itself.

Comment: Thanks you, Ciro for your answer again. My fundamental question was of simulation confidence. That is, how much should I trust my simulation results when I run user applications with HPI core model? I just want to say that my simulation results can be trusted with X% confidence. Can I ask you what a reasonable way to translate or present gem5 simulation results would be?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want, and I agree that this is an important information, but I don't know any public sources for it :-( One can argue however that since gem5 is used for arch exploration a few years before hardware, by the time your feature goes live everything may have changed, so maybe great accuracy is not so fundamental, as long as the key mechanisms are more or less representative. It's a difficult problem.